# Combining wp_insert_post() and update_post_meta()

Tags: wp-insert-post, post-meta

How combine `wp_insert_post()` and wp `update_post_meta`?

I need first insert my Post then, update the Post. Let me know about an example? I want a sample for my future projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 2020 Update:

In case you landed here looking for a refresher on how to update the post's meta, as I did, see the following edit:

The post array argument in `wp_insert_post()` takes an inner array called `meta_input`, so you can create the post with proper meta in one database query.

```php
$page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title'    =>  'Team',
    'menu_order'    =>  '2',
    'post_content'  =>  '[team]',
    'post_type'     =>  'page',
    'post_parent'   =>  1,
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',
    'meta_input'    =>  array(
        'your_meta_key' => 'your meta value'
    ),
));
```

The same can be done for `wp_update_post()`:

```php
wp_update_post(array(
  'post_title' => 'About',
  'ID' => $page_id,
  'meta_input' =>  array(
    'your_meta_key' => 'your meta value'
  ),
));
```

#### Original Answer:

is this code enough for you?

```
/*
** wp_insert_post - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post
** function will create a new post and return a $interger shich is a ID of the new created post.
*/
$page_id = wp_insert_post(array(
    'post_title'    =>  'Team',
    'menu_order'    =>  '2',
    'post_content'  =>  '[team]',
    'post_type'     =>  'page',
    'post_parent'   =>  1,
    'post_status'   =>  'publish',
));

/*
**  wp_update_post - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post
** function is simular (actually its almost alias) of wp_insert_post
** it will update a post 
** $arguments that passed to wp_update_post is a same as in wp_insert_post but require additional argument ID whish is id of the post
*/
wp_update_post(array('post_title' => 'About', 'ID' => $page_id));
```

Comment: thanks this corrected? 
$my_post = wp_insert_post (array(
                                'post_title'    => $ff[0],
                                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                                'post_author'   => 1,
                                'post_type'     => 'products',
                              ));
                                 
       $new_p =  wp_insert_post( $my_post );
                            wp_set_post_terms($new_p,$term_s_child->term_id,'phone');
                            update_post_meta($new_p, 'price', $ff[1]);

Comment: NO. In your example you creating post (first instance of wp_insert_post with some arguments) - than you tring to create a new post with invalid argument (which is ID of previously creacted post)... next code line skipped.

take a look to code reference - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: as will be right then? I need after the creation of the post, update it

Comment: so use wp_update_post (same arguments + post id (ID)) - see http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_post

Comment: Oleg, please add explanations to your answer, not as a comment. Thanks.